# *= operator in formula language in lotus notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

Please tell me what is the role of *= operator in below piece of code

```
@If(@UserRoles *= "[admin]" ; "" ; @Return(""));
```

It is formula language used in lotus notes databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a Permuted Equal.

```
 if a="this" or a="that" or a="other" then....
```

So this code sets to "" if is admin, otherwise it bails with a "".

Agree with  @rhsatrhs, this is unclear and should be written using a normal =.

Here is a [link](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/2a483322f7b71a4485256c54004bde56?OpenDocument) to the Permutations operators official documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using it because got to do what has been assigned.

Comment: In this case, the permuted equal operator is completely unnecessary and should be removed for clarity.  When comparing a list to a scalar, as is occurring here, the scalar is compared to each element of the list.  In other words, you get the if a="this" or a="that" behavior with a regular "=" operator, so @UserRoles = "[admin]" is all you need -- even if the user does have multiple roles.  The "*=" operator is only useful when comparing two lists, in which case every element of listA is compared with every element of listB.

Comment: And no, *= is not like the ternary operator in other languages.  Assigning an @If statement to a variable is the Notes formula equivalent of the ternary operator.  I.e., the Notes formula x:= @If(condition,value1,value2); is the equivalent of C or Java's x = condition ? value1 : vaule2;